# Stored procedure not giving accurate results from java code

Tags: java, jakarta-ee, jdbc

I have stored procedure that searches persons on basis of any given inputs (any bio data e.g blood group, name, identity no. etc. taking almost 26 inputs).

I am executing a stored procedure (sql server) from java using `Callable Statement` `preparecall` method. Previously I had a problem that my stored procedure was not giving any results (0 row result) whenever the string input was passed in one of its many input parameters. On other hand gave correct results when any integer type parameter value was passed but when I changed `jdbc` driver from `jdbc:odbc` driver to `sqlserver` driver
(`driver name=com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerDrive`), the problem was solved.

Now my new problem is that when my procedure `procSearch2`, that is taking 16 inputs, is running it gives results perfectly fine with the same `Connection` variable of `jdbc` driver (changed one), but the other procedure, which have 27 inputs (`procSearch1`) is not giving any results even with `int` or `string` input values passed.

It does not give any error it just returns me 0 row result where it should return 3 rows result.

here is the code

```
 CallableStatement stmt=connect.prepareCall("{CALL  procSearch1(?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?)}");
 stmt.setInt(1,0);
 stmt.setString(2,"");
 stmt.setString(3,"");
 .
 .
 .
stmt.setInt(27,0);
 ResultSet result=stmt.executeQuery();

 if(result!=null)
{
   System.out.println(result.getRow()); 
  while(result.next)
  {
    System.out.println(result.getString("Name"));

   }

 }
```

Comment: Have you tried executing the second procedure from backend to see whether it returns any data?

Comment: yea i debugged at each line and checked my procSearch2 gives results but procSearch1 doesnot. it jsut returns empty row where it should have returned 3 rows according to when sp run in sql server.

Answer (score 0):

You need to set an output paramater to the CallableStatement to read the return value of the sp.
Something like this (exception handling omitted for brevity):

```
CallableStatement  stmt = connection.prepareCall("{? = call procSearch1(?,?,?) }");
stmt.registerOutParameter(1, java.sql.Types.INTEGER);
stmt.setString(2, "abc");
stmt.setString(3, "xyz");
stmt.execute();
Integer sp_return_value = stmt.getInt(1);
```

EDIT:
Based on your comment, if your SP returns the result of a Select, ie, a resultSet, I think you need to use statement.execute() instead of the executeQuery().

See http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms378630.aspx & http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms378487.aspx.

So, your code should be something like:

```
CallableStatement stmt=connect.prepareCall("{CALL  procSearch1(?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?)}");
stmt.setInt(1,0);
stmt.setString(2,"");
stmt.setString(3,"");
.
.
.
stmt.setInt(27,0);
ResultSet result = stmt.execute();

if(result!=null) {
    System.out.println(result.getRow()); 
    while(result.next) {
        System.out.println(result.getString("Name"));
    }
}
```

Comment: there are 5 returned output values of sp(5 columns of a table) some string and some integer values. for that do i have to add only 1 output parameter ? before call proc syntax i.e "{ ? = call procSearch1(?,?,?,?)}". And also the other procedure i was talking about is giving perfectly fine results even without using registerOutParameter() or defining output parameter.

Comment: i did **ResultSet result = stmt.execute();** but its giving me same result of 0 row result when i print ** System.out.println(result.getRow()); ** inside result!=null block. Also m printing stmt.getUpdateCount() after execute statement and it gives me **-1** result